# Approval After action.json Update

Tags: actions-on-google

I updated my action.json for my Google action and uploaded it, but do I need to get my app re-approved now? It shows the modified time and "publishing" so I think the answer is no, but wanted to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you updated the action package, then you do need to resubmit for review. However, if the content in the webhook is updated, then you do not need to resubmit it.

Comment: Ok I can confirm now it definitely didn't get published after I updated the action.json.  So this answer is correct.  Any Googlers out there though, there was a bug, it wouldn't let me resubmit so I had change something in the info form to get it to submit.

Comment: Hey @PizzaPanther could you please let me know what is the project ID so I could follow up on this issue? 
Thank you.

Comment: neutron-academy can tell you more weirdness too :-)

Like it said it was republishing even though nothing changed officially. I updated the action.json and it immediately went into republising, that is what was most confusing. And apparently it just published the same thing not the changes.